# If $(F_n)$ is increasing and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F_1\dotsb F_n}{F_{n+1}}=0$ then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{F_n}$ is irrational

Tags: sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers

Let $F_n$ be integers, and $F_1<F_2<\cdots<F_n<\cdots$. Suppose that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F_1F_2\cdots F_{n-1}}{F_n}=0.$$ Prove then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{F_n}$$ is convergence, and the sum of which is irrational.

Comment: This is a PSQ, but I think it is an interesting one.  Why close this, as opposed to some of the other incredible PSQs we've had in the past? (I, for one, think this should remain open)

Comment: @anorton No self-work and "Really difficult, isn't it?" might have been annoying to some.

Comment: @LordSoth I agree that the "Really difficult..." comment made me want to close the question at first, but then I realized that Stack Exchange is really more about the *question* than the particular phrasing of the asker.  (Because I could go and edit the "Really difficult" comment away right now... `:)` )

Comment: Why is this question on hold? Can't it be done by modifying the proof to show e is irrational but ending up with an integer equaling the product of two terms both going to 0 and thus is <1.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792583

Answer (score 1):

There are many exceptionally slow sequences, consider ${\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}F_i\over F_n}=\frac 1{\ln n}$ or even slower versions.  But whatever sequence $1\over f(n)$ is chosen for the RHS, assuming $F_1$ is positive, we have $f(n)\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$, thus

$$F_n=f(n)\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}F_i\ge \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}F_i$$

Then, assuming $\exists i:F_i\ge 2$, for all but a finite set of terms, we have

$$\sum_{i=k}^\infty\frac 1{F_i}\le \sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac 1{2^{2i}}$$

And thus $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac 1{F_i}$ converges under the specified assumptions.