# If $(a_n)$ is increasing and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_1\dotsb a_n}=+\infty$ then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{a_n}$ is irrational

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

> $\{a_n\}$ is a  strictly increasing sequence of positive integers such that 
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_1a_2\dotsb a_n}=+\infty$$
> then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{a_n}$ is an irrational number

proof by contradiction?  $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{a_n}=\frac pq$,

I also try the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{a_n}$, without any progress. The classical proof of  irrational of $e$ use Taylor formula

The problem was proposed by Jose Luis Daz-Barrero. If $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{ a_n}=+\infty$, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{a_n}$ is irrational, too?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Presumably, you know this is true? Where did you get this result? In what context?

Comment: Hint: If $x = \frac{p}{q}$ is a rational number, then for any positive integer $N$, the fractional part of $Nx$, $\{ Nx \} = Nx - \lfloor Nx \rfloor$, is either $0$ or $\ge \frac{1}{q}$. What can you say about $\{ a_1 a_2 \ldots a_n \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_k} \}$ for large $n$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose towards contradiction that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{a_n}=\frac pq \quad \quad p, q \in \mathbb{Z}^+
$$
Let $M = 2qe$.
Then choose $N$ such that for $n > N$, $a_{n} > M a_1 a_2 \ldots a_{n-1}$.
Multiplying the above by $q a_1 a_2 \ldots a_N$, we have
$$
pa_1 a_2 \ldots a_N
= \sum_{n=1}^N q a_1 a_2 \ldots a_{n-1} a_{n+1} \ldots a_N
+ \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{qa_1a_2\ldots a_N}{a_n}
$$
implying
$$
\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{qa_1a_2\ldots a_N}{a_n} \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
But then
$$
\frac{qa_1a_2\ldots a_N}{a_n} < \frac{q a_1 a_2 \ldots a_N}{M a_1 a_2 \ldots a_{n-1}}
$$
so
\begin{align*}
0
&< \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{qa_1a_2\ldots a_N}{a_n} \\
&< \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{q}{Ma_{N+1}a_{N+2} \ldots a_{n-1}} \\
&< \frac{q}{M} \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n - N - 1)!}
\quad \quad \text{(since } a_n \text{ is increasing)}
 \\
&= \frac{q}{M}e = \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{align*}
which is a contradiction, as there is no integer between $0$ and $\frac12$.