# Is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{a_n}$ irrational?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

> $\{a_n\}$ is a  strictly increasing sequence of positive integers such that 
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{ a_n}=+\infty$$
> Can one conclude that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{a_n}$ is an irrational number? a transcendental  number?

A special case is $a_n=n!$, $e$ is a transcendental  number.

Another special example is [Liouville number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number) $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac1{10^{n!}}$ is a transcendental  number, too.

so the question, if true, may be difficult.

The question is a generalization of [If $(a_n)$ is increasing and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_1\dotsb a_n}=+\infty$ then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{a_n}$ is irrational](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792583/sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1a-n-is-irrational)

Comment: I have heard about specific classes of sequences that converge faster than a geometric series and always have irrational limits, but I cannot remember the exact hypothesis. Also, if we allow the $a_n$ to be non-integers, it's clearly not true.

Comment: @ᛥᛥᛥ Whoops, I missed that!

Comment: In the case or $e$, you have $a_n\mid a_{n+1}$ for every $n$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is NO.

Consider the [Sylvester's sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_sequence) ([OEIS A000058](http://oeis.org/A000058)):

$$(s_0, s_1, \ldots ) = (
2, 3, 7, 43, 1807, 3263443, 10650056950807, \ldots)$$
defined recursively by the relation

$$s_n = \begin{cases}
2,& n = 0,\\
s_{n-1}(s_{n-1}-1)+1,& n > 0
\end{cases}$$

It is known that its reciprocals give an infinite [Egyptian fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction) representation of number one:

$$1 = \frac12 + \frac13 + \frac17 + \frac{1}{43} + \frac{1}{1807} + \cdots$$

It is also easy to check $\displaystyle\;\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{s_{k+1}}{s_k} = \infty\;$. If you set $a_n = s_{n-1}$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$, you get a counterexample of what you want to show. i.e $\displaystyle\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n}\;$ need not be irrational.

Comment: To me it seems clearer to state the definition by saying $s_{n+1} = 1 + \prod_{k=1}^n s_n$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy that might be true. However, I start from constructing the infinite Egyptian fraction myself, come up the recursion relation I wrote down before I locate the name and other properties of this sequence.

Answer (score 10):

The conjecture is false.

Take $S_0 = 0$, and for $n=1,2,\cdots$ define $a_n$ to be the least integer such that $S_{n-1}+1/a_n < 1$.  Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/a_n = 1$ but $a_{n+1}/a_n$ grows very fast...
$$
                               a_1 = 2\\
                               a_2 = 3\\
                               a_3 = 7\\
                               a_4 = 43\\
                              a_5 = 1807\\
                            a_6 = 3263443\\
                         a_7 = 10650056950807\\
                  a_8 = 113423713055421844361000443\\
     a_9 = 12864938683278671740537145998360961546653259485195807
$$